# In Scala, how do I call methods on an object called `+` without getting a syntax error?

Tags: scala, syntax, syntax-error

I have an object called `+` with a method called `B`. I'm trying to call this method like so:

```
object + {
    def B() = Console.println("'Sup, world?")
}

object Main extends App {
    +.B()
}
```

(Ideone link: http://ideone.com/0OyKw2)

But this gives me a syntax error:

```
Main.scala:6: error: illegal start of simple expression
    +.B()
         ^
```

I've tried a couple of different ways of calling this method, like `+ .B`, `(+).B`, `` `+`.B ``, `` (`+`).B ``, and `( + ).B`. I haven't found anything that works yet.

Can I call this method somehow, or am I best off just using a different name for the object?

Comment: It is a terrible idea to have an object named `+` and methods in scala usually start with lowercase, so `b()` instead of `B()`

Comment: @Tanner Swett Is there a reason you want to name your class like an operator? Maybe we can find a more idiomatic scala pattern to achieve the operator effect you want.

Comment: @rmin I originally named the class `AppendVect`, but I ended up with a lot of types looking like `AppendVect[MyFirstType, AppendVect[MySecondType, MyThirdType]]`. Since `AppendVect` is a very important class, I figured a name like `+` would be appropriate, since then I could write `MyFirstType + (MySecondType + MyThirdType)`. I tried renaming the class to `++` instead, and that seems to be working out well.

Comment: @Tanner Swett It looks like maybe you're building something similar to an HList from the shapeless library. It might be worth checking that out to avoid reinventing it.

Comment: Seems to work for me. Is this a Scala version thing? I tried with 2.12.1, which version did you get the error with?

Comment: @lutzh I think I'm using some 2.10 version. You can also see this error on the Ideone page at http://ideone.com/0OyKw2, and I don't know what version of Scala Ideone is using.

Comment: @lutzh I checked the version, and it's 2.10.6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are certainly best off just using a "safer" name, but this works:

```
$plus.B
```

Comment: This relies on a particular encoding of a particular version of a particular implementation on a particular platform. I wouldn't bet on this working, e.g. on Scala-native, or on a newer version.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Good point. I think we can all agree that the whole thing is a bad idea. But any idea why it works with `++` instead of `+` and also with Scala 2.12 (both assertions from comments above)?